# How can outofboundexception will be solved?

Tags: android, database, while-loop, android-cursor

I am accessing phonebook through one query and getting last call details from other query. The problem is that when i am getting date from my manged cursor i get outofbound exception and my application crashed. please help me i only want to take recent call date of every number(if not null).

my cursor query for getting phonebook details is:-

```
Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER}, null, null, null);
          startManagingCursor(mCursor);
```

query for getting  recent call date of a particular number:-

```
Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, selection,null, Order);
```

Loop in which iam getting recent call date of a number that was taken from phonebook details cursor:-

```
 mCursor.moveToFirst();

          while(!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {

                JSONObject contact = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject parentCont = new JSONObject();

                 String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                 String number = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                 String selection = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER+"="+number;
                 String Order = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
                          Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, selection,null, Order);
                          managedCursor.moveToNext();   
              String     callDate = managedCursor.getString(managedCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE));

                Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));

                //String dateColumn = cursorcalllog.getString(cursorcalllog.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE));

                 Log.d("CONTACT", "Name: " + name + "| Number: " + number+"Recently Called"+callDayTime);
```

Logcat Errors:-

```
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.socialize_us/com.example.socialize_us.CustomTabActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.socialize_us/com.example.socialize_us.PhoneBookActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2111)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1251)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4666)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.socialize_us/com.example.socialize_us.PhoneBookActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1924)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:682)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:346)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at com.example.socialize_us.CustomTabActivity.onCreate(CustomTabActivity.java:33)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4510)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2048)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  ... 11 more
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:400)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:241)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at com.example.socialize_us.PhoneBookActivity.onCreate(PhoneBookActivity.java:107)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4510)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2048)
04-03 05:33:43.090: E/AndroidRuntime(963):  ... 21 more
```

Comment: You are not getting data in cursor using your query. "Index 0 requested, with a size of 0".

Comment: No value is getting in to the cursor ,Its null

Comment: @Arju Cursor is empty, it is not null

Comment: @pragnani Ya thats what i mean .Make Sure the Query works Fine Before working with the result.

Comment: test the result of mCursor.moveToFirst();

Comment: iam gettin all phonebook contacts when i used only one cursor i.e mCursor but when i used managed cursor for getting recent call with a number i get this exception.

Comment: @Saad There might be no call information in your device, so it returns empty cursor, when you are tring to read values from it, it throws null pointer Exception..Dial few calls in your emulator and also format your code such if moveToFirst() return true read the first record and rest based on the move to next value as I have suggested in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cursor is empty and When you are trying to get the values from the mcusor which is empty you are getting cursor IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Try to read the values from the cursor  in this format to avoid IndexoutOfBoundsException

```
if(mCursor.moveToFirst())
{

  do
{
...
...
}
while(mCursor.moveToNext())

}
```

Comment: mcursor is not empty when i used managed cursor in loop i get this exception

Comment: @Saad What Ever the cursor have used, if it not empty its ok, but if it is empty then it will throw the same exception for you. So read the data if avaible in the cursor. Format your code as above

Answer (score 0):

The error  : Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: **Index 0 requested, with a size of 0**
you must add the exception if the value equal 0 there is no information.